# get object from array by key name

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to get an object from an array by its key name.

Array:

```js
let input = [
    id1: {},
    id2: {},
    id3: {},
]

console.log(input);
```

And I only want the object with the key `id2`. How can I filter the object from the array?

Comment: That's not even valid JS.

Comment: I have updated your code, just to show that syntax is not valid, you can run the snippet and check...

Comment: Arrays don't have keys in JavaScript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @ritaj stated, in the code you provided, that was invalid syntax, I'm going to assume that you mean to implement something like this, via using the [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function. However, if you want to find multiple objects, you could always use the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function, as you can see in the second example, it's returning an array containing both the object with the property `id2` and `id3`.

```js
var array = [
  {id1: {}},
  {id2: {}},
  {id3: {}},
];

console.log(array.find(({id2}) => id2));
```

```js
var array = [
  {id1: {}},
  {id2: {}},
  {id3: {}},
];

console.log(array.filter(({id2, id3}) => id3 || id2));
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all it is not a valid `JS` object or a `JSON` string.

If it is an object it should be defined as follows.

```
{
    "id1": {
        "some": "property"
    },
    "id2": {
        "some": "property"
    },
    "id3": {
        "some": "property"
    }
}
```

Let's call it `parentObject`.

In that case you can access the desired object simply by the property.

```
parentObject.id2 
or
parentObject['id2']
```

In case this is an array it should be defined as follows.

```
  [{
        "id1": {
            "some": "property"
        }
    },
    {
        "id2": {
            "some": "property"
        }
    },
    {
        "id3": {
            "some": "property"
        }
    }
  ]
```

Let's call it `parentArray`.
And you can find it using the following code, for instance

```
var targetObject= parentArray.find(x => x.id2 !== undefined);
```

This will return the first match if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays have numerical indexes only.

If you want only one single item of the array and you know the index:

```
var myArray = [{a: 'a'}, {b: 'b'}]
var iWantedIndex = 1;
var myObject = {};
myObject[iWantedIndex] = myArray[iWantedIndex];
```

If you need more complex checks or more than one element from the array you can use [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) or a classic *for-loop*.